# Subquery returned more than 1 value in SSMS 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2014, ssms-2016

I have a database created in SQL Server 2014 x64 express edition with SSMS 2014 and have some table in the database. I backup the database with this tsql

```
BACKUP DATABASE dbFile
TO DISK='D:\dbFile_170125.bak' WITH FORMAT;
```

In other computer, i have SQL Server 2016 x64 express edition with SSMS 2016.
I create new database, then i restore database from file "dbFile_170125.bak" with replace option. The restore is success.

The problem is when i expand the **Tables** in Object Explorer in SSMS 2016, it show error :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:512)

In SSMS 2014, there is no problem like that.
Perhaps someone can help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Same problem here, I installed the latest SMSS update yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple users have the problem, it seems, for now, the only solution is to roll back the update.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/27c39cf6-555a-4dad-b1b3-db14b63ba5e6/ssms-2016-error-when-expanding-tables?forum=sqltools

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/22c906d5-fbbb-474f-9b63-08abb1b0a9bc/ssms-2016-error-when-expanding-tables-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value?forum=ssdt

edit: and here is the bug report https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32898901-microsoft-sql-server-management-studio-error-on

Comment: SSMS team has been notified and they are currently working on a fix. SSMS download page has been updated.