# How to Uninstall SQL Server Management Studio 2016?

Tags: ssms-2016

I have problem with SSMS 16.5.2 in this quetion, ([Subquery returned more than 1 value in SSMS 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846001/subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-in-ssms-2016)). 
I already uninstall Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio from control panel. But after uninstall, the shortcut program in start menu already exist and if i open the program, it work correctly. How to uninstall it ?

My computer have win 10 pro x64, sql server 2016 x64 sp1, visual studio 2015 community edition update 3

Comment: Have you tried installing the latest version without uninstalling the previous one?

Comment: Already install

Answer (score 0):

You should uninstall it by 'setup.exe' first time has been installed, Not in 'Programs and Features' in control panel

Answer (score -1):

uninstall "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - 16.4.1"